# jQuery Mobile popup that doesn't move when scrolling the page

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, scroll

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 RC1. I have a popup that I create programmatically at the bottom of my page and close after a few seconds using setTimeout (toast notification). It works very well, however if I happen to scroll the page while the popup is displayed, the popup gets scrolled too. I would like the popup not to move, i.e. stay in its position relative to the screen, not relative to the page. Is there a way to do that ?

I have tried playing with the data-position-to attribute in the HTML element, with the positionTo option of the "open" method, and tried placing the popup element inside a fixed transparent footer, none of these resulted in the desired behavior.

Comment: I too have a similar problem.

Comment: Was this solved or not? I am having the same issue @Akshatha

Comment: No. It went as an open issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week. Finally solved it using [modal dialog](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49735179/dialog-data-transfer.html) instead of popups.

For popups, I could find following.

```
$("#myPopup").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function () {
        $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
    }
});
```

Which helped me in prevention of closing the dialog while user touched outside of popup. But scrolling issue was still there. So I changed all popups to modal dialogs. Hope it helps someone.